# Trying to "fix" the size of my buttons on Squarespace

Tags: css, squarespace

On the homepage of [staterequirement.com](https://staterequirement.com) I have a group of buttons, one for each state. The site is built on Squarespace.

Squarespace gives you three "button sizes," each with their own CSS properties. They all, however change the size of buttons based on the amount of text.

When placing all of the buttons in columns, they look very wonky, because they are all different sizes, and run into each other.

My goal is to have these five rows of buttons fit together in straight columns, and all the buttons the same size.

I thought of making all of the buttons into images, but that would take away the hover effect that the buttons have.

`.medium-button-shape-rounded .sqs-block-button .sqs-block-button-element--medium, .large-button-shape-rounded .sqs-block-button .sqs-block-button-element--large
      { width: 100px}`

This has been suggested to me, and it does make all of the rows buttons the same size, but it cuts off "Massachusetts", and the columns are not evenly spaced.

I think the answer is a combination of the code that was offered to me, and a padding change.

Please help!

P.S. -- If there is a better solution, to this issue, I am absolutely open to hearing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following CSS will help you achieve what you're looking for. Besides decreasing the padding and font size in order to make all the buttons more compact and a single-line high, it makes use of the `min-width` property. This makes all buttons that are less than 130px wide to be made to be 130px wide, which is around the width of the longest button in the set (South Carolina I believe).

```
.sqs-block-button .sqs-block-button-element--medium {
    padding: 14px 18px;
    font-size: 11px;
    min-width: 130px;
}
```

As mentioned by Serge Inácio, you have an additional problem in that you're attempting to divide Squarespace's 12-column grid into 5 columns, which it will not do equally (it is a column-based system, even if it doesn't *feel* like it). Therefore, consider using 4 columns instead. With 4 columns, you may then be able to adjust the values in the above CSS upward a bit. You may also notice that at certain widths, buttons in adjacent columns overlap one-another. Going to four columns may help this as well, but if it doesn't, it should at least make the problem easier to fix.

Comment: Thank you for the code!  This has solved the issue.  Also, I appreciate you letting me know that there is at 12 column grid. I need to get over the fact that 50 divides by 5 so well, and just put it into a 4 column grid.

I really appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0):

I see you use diferent col sizes in your code: 3 x `col sqs-col-2 span-2` and 2x `col sqs-col-3 span-3` Having a total of 5 columns, if you reduce it to 4 columns you will have more space (i.e. 4x `col sqs-col-3 span-3`) and add the code that was suggested to you. if it still cuts off you may be can split it into 3x `col sqs-col-4 span-4` or make the font a little smaller.

Hope I helped a bit :)

Regards

Comment: Thank you for the response!
The way that the columns work is not actually "columns", per se. It is more like, I drag them next to each other, and they automatically space themselves evenly across the page.  So each row is actually it's own column setup.

I could drop the entire "table" into 4 columns, and that would solve the run-in issue, but the buttons would still all be different sizes.

Do you think there is a way to reduce padding size on the text inside the buttons themselves, if the word is large? ex. Massachusetts.

I truly appreciate your help :)

Comment: yes, or to 3 columns. After that you could add the following to your css: `.sqs-block-button-element--medium { width: 90% !important;}` you can add percentage or pixels if you like, it is up to you.

Comment: Thank you for the help!  I will put the width: 90% in as a comment, as I won't use it now, but it may come in handy soon!